# iptables not working on macvlan traffic in container

Tags: docker, iptables

I have a host with one interface `eth0`, IP `10.0.10.10/24`. I start up docker, add a container, no network. I then create a macvlan device on `eth0`, give it IP `10.0.10.20/24`, and put it in the container.

Both the host and the container now have full network access.

I then create an iptables rule on the host to drop all traffic to or from the container's IP `10.0.10.20`. The rules do not work, and traffic gets through.

Of course, if I do it from within the container (either `ip netns exec $PID iptables ...` or by giving the container `NET_ADMIN` capabilities), it works.

Should the iptables rules of the underlying host not filter the traffic?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this one?

Comment: Not directly. I will write an answer in here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this is: you cannot do it. When using the bridge, then the traffic runs into the host and out, so it hits the host's ip stack. When you use macvlan, the only ip stack is the one in the container, so the iptables rules on the host never are called.

The only way to do it is to change the iptables rules **inside** the container.

If you do not want to give the container access, e.g. if you want to control the container, then use `ip netns exec ...` from the host itself, which will control the iptables rules in the container without giving the container itself control.

I wrote a script that does that. It is available at https://github.com/deitch/ctables and licensed MIT.

Comment: Thank you. That's also the conclusion I reached - The issue I am having is that I do not want to use bridges (they affect network measurement results more than macvlan does), but account/set quotas on the traffic used inside the container *and* give the container NET_ADMIN privileges. So the only option I have is to keep checking regularly that my iptables rules inside the container are still in place and working.

Comment: @relet why give the container NET_ADMIN? Why not use the `ctables` solution I outlined above, where you control it from the host?

Comment: And, yes, bridge performance impacts. It doesn't matter for most deployments, but for some it very much does. I first did macvlan with a financial institution streaming prices. Every microsecond mattered. I did a detailed analysis comparing docker bridge, bare metal, SR-IOV, macvlan, and a few others in terms of throughput and latency. I proposed it as a talk at dockercon and containercon this year, we will see what they say. I also want to redo with Calico.

Comment: Both actually - the containers need NET_ADMIN, since they are a range of network experiments written by third parties. I have to find the balance between containing them, and letting them do their work, but I can still initialize them with meaningful rules.
 
Did you settle on macvlan after your analysis?

Comment: Oh, so they need it anyways, and you want to control access from the outside? Ah, then you cannot use iptables for that. macvlan just doesn't go through the host's iptables. You will have to do it at the network level.

Comment: Yes, I did settle on macvlan. It was faster and lower overhead than the alternatives. However, I do not recall what the results were for SR-IOV with a high-end network adapter, and I didn't check Calico at the time.

Comment: Same here. We settled on monitoring the rx/tx values on the macvlan interfaces to implement quotas without requiring any actual iptables rules - which is possible since the interfaces are used exclusively by one container.